# How to modify a class implementation in a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, patch

I have a .NET assembly without strong sign, is it possible to patch a specified class to:

1. change a method's implementation
2. add methods
3. add fields

Comment: ILDasm | modify | ILAsm

Comment: Sounds great, I've try ILSpy to dasm to c#, but failed to recompile it again, hope ILDasm helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Libraries such as Mono.Cecil give you access to every bits of an assemblies by parsing them as MSIL containers. You can then easily modify whatever you like. So this question is not suitable for StackOverflow, but Google.

Comment: Thanks Lex, actually before I post questions here I always try to find answer by Google, but with little luck. I'ill try Mono.Cecil.

Comment: It would be really nice to link an example. Why? I did exact thing you proposed and  Google brought me to there. And pretty sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: The issue is, I looking for tool I can in automation script, not a way to do it by hand (for what I can use dnSpy). But writing such tool is an option, I guess, but not a desired one.

Comment: Ok, to clarify: I strongly opposing "just google it" kind of answers. Each of them making internet a slightly worse space.

Comment: If the whole site gets rid of "is it possible" kind of questions, you won't see such an answer either. But does it really matter much when the whole conversation was carried out in 2016? When you have a different question to ask like "The issue is, I looking for tool I can in automation script, not a way to do it by hand", you should post a new question and see what kind of answers you might get.

Comment: "is it possible" imply "how to do it", there is no point of asking it otherwise. Also, I have multiple things to say, but this discussion for some meta- section, and is not relevant to the question of assembly patching.

Answer (score 0):

As things stands in 2022, yes, it can be done.

It depends on exactly what you want to do:
If you want to patch binary one and forever, you can use dnSpy: .net assembly decompiller/inspector/debugger/editor:
https://github.com/dnSpyEx/dnSpy

It you want to patch an assembly in memory without editing file on disk (mostly used in game modding), you can use
MonoMod (https://github.com/MonoMod/MonoMod) or Harmony (https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony) or even good old (and somewhat obsolete) Microsoft's Detours